# Hazard ratios - one unit increase for a continuous variable measuring diversity (Blau index/ coefficient of variation), how to interpret?

Tags: cox-model, hazard, coefficient-of-variation, diversity

I am having difficulty understanding how to interpret a one-unit increase/decrease for continuous variables in a Cox model.
Specifically, I have created the variables gender, age & nationality diversity using the Blau index and coefficient of variation.

So for example, I have a Hazard Ratio of 1.7 for nationality diversity. This means a 70% increased hazard for a one-unit increase compared with my reference group. How should I interpret the one-unit change given the below formulas?

The Blau index is $1 - \sum_{i=1}^R p_i^2$.

my variable ranges from 0 to 0.5 for Gender diversity (since it's a dummy) and 0 to 1 for nationality diversity, with 0 being 0 diversity and 0.5/1 being max. diversity possible.

The coefficient of variation is SD / mean.

The coefficient of variation in my sample ranges from 0 to 1.24

Refering to Backman & Kohlhase (2020)(https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/jors.12488): they mention the one-unit increase (they used the Theil index to measure cultural diversity).

[image])

They mention their mean for cultural diversity in the full sample is 0.332 and sd = 0.331 and the hazard ratio is 1.47. They mention that given a one-unit change is a drastic change, they used the sd to calculate the hazard ratio with the following formula [((1.47)^(0.331)) − 1].

Comment: As a side note:  Currently I believe it might not be recommended to use the hazard ratio (exponentiated coefficient) but rather just the coefficient

Comment: I wouldn't emphasize per-unit changes but rather would show the estimated relationship between the continuous covariate and log relative hazard, from say the 10th smallest value to the 10th largest value of the covariate.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, thank you for the suggestion! May I ask how this would typically be done?

Comment: Do you mean hazard ratio when you say hazard rate?

Comment: It's marginal to your question, and pedantic if you wish, but references of the form authors (year) are hard work for anyone not in your sub-sub-field who doesn't know the literature you know. If a reference is important at all, give the full reference somehow, a URL or DOI or reference as would be expected in a proper publication.

Comment: @NickCox thanks for pointing it out, I will make sure to add the URL/DOI in next posts (I have added it to this post as well)

Comment: @NickCox, yes sorry I mean hazard ratio. I apologize, I must have used them interchangeably as a non-native speaker, but indeed they mean two different things.

Comment: Here are examples of partial effect plots to which I alluded above: https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/coxcase#fig-coxcase-shapes